# Upload multiple files with nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I'm using a paperclip for attaching multiple images to a table row, but unicorn get a time out and don't complete the upload. I need know how to make multiple files upload from nginx, without getting this time out.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and I've switched Unicorn to Rainbows! http://rainbows.bogomips.org/ with minor configuration changes.
As they claim:

> Rainbows! is an HTTP server for sleepy Rack applications. It is based
>   on unicorn, but designed to handle applications that expect long
>   request/response times and/or slow clients.

For me that worked for years.